Send and receive socket without opening the html web page
I am having a django project where I have chat.html, journey.html, and manager.html.
chat.html
const socket = new WebSocket('ws://' + window.location.host + '/ws/chat/room1/');
...
async function trigger_journey() {
    var selectedJourney = document.getElementById("journey_dropdown").value;
    const response = await fetch(`/fetch_journey/?journey_name=${selectedJourney}`);
    const data = await response.json();
    console.log("data:", data)
    const elementId = 'messageDisplay';
    const chatContainer = document.getElementById(elementId);
    socket.send(JSON.stringify({ type: 'trigger_journey', sender: 'Agent', journeyid: data.journeyid, journeyorder: data.journeyorder, requestId: requestId, email: email, name: uname, phone: phone, chat: chatContainer.innerHTML, department: Department }));
}

journey.html
socket.onmessage = function (event) {
    const message = JSON.parse(event.data);
           
    if (message.type === 'trigger_journey') {
        requestid = message.requestid;
        journeyid = message.journeyid;
        journeyorder = message.journeyorder;
        chat = message.chat;
        department = message.department;
        ...
                     
                if (activityid === 'emailevent') {    
                    sendEmail();
                }              
                else if (activityid === 'approvalevent') {
                    sendApproval()   
                }
            });
    }
}
            
async function sendApproval() {
    ...
    if (sendToForExistingJourneyId === "Manager") {
        data = {
            'type': 'manager_approval',
            'sendTo': sendTo,
            'requestId': requestid,
            'name': uname,
            'phoneNumber': phoneNumber,
            'requestDetails': ureqdetails,
            'sender': "agent"
        };
        //"sent to manager");
    }
    socket.send(JSON.stringify(data));

manager_dashboard.html
socket.onmessage = function(event) {
    //"--------------manager_approval--------------")
    var data = JSON.parse(event.data);
    //data)
    if (data.type === 'manager_approval' ) {
        handleWebSocketMessage(data);
    }
   
};

One of the flows is that I am sending socket for triggering journey from chat.html. And in the journey.html, I have a flow for approval where the socket gets sent to manager.html.
This flow is working only when I keep all these 3 pages open in browser. But if I don't keep the "journey" page open in a browser, the socket is not getting received and send is not happening from "journey".
This should work without the need to open "journey" page in the browser. How can I do that?

How are you "sending a socket" to a HTML page? It's hard to help without seeing your actual code here.

I've updated with code. please check

You would need to persist the messages (in e.g. a Django model) and show them from there.

Can you please elaborate further?
How is it possible to trigger journey from chat page and send approval to manager without sending socket?

Have your backend for the channel process the message and save the new Journey into your database.

We already have models defined and have our journey stored.
But how can I receive data simultaneously from chat page to manager from DB without refreshing like how it works for sockets? Because depending on the first socket only the second socket works like as I've given for approval.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
